# iPad: Split view with gesture control?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, gesture

Is it possible to make a split view app on the iPad an integrate gesture control, so you could swipe left and right to switch between the "rows" of the table in the RootViewController?

Comment: Everything is possible. The question is how.

Comment: @RadekPro-Grammer: do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your detail controller a UIScrollViewController.  If user taps a row in the rootViewController, scroll to the appropriate "page" of the scroll view.  If the user swipes left or right, scroll to the previous/next page.  If your data is not images, but rather data that changes inside a form that does not change, then you don't need a scroll view, you just need a gesture recognizer to step forward and backward through your data.

Comment: @Mike: the data is a collection of PDF's.  Right now in my RootView I have three PDF's being stored and displayed on the table.  When I select a PDF the detail view pulls up the selected file.  Right now I'm trying to make it so that by scrolling left or right you'll either +1 or -1 to the row index and display the next or prev page.  Does this make sense?

Comment: When you swipe right, do you want to show the next PDF, or the next page of the current PDF?  The former is a lot easier.  There are a couple of issues here though.  If the user swipes quickly, before you're done loading the PDF, you'll need to handle that, so do your loads on a background thread.  You'll also need to keep track of several PDF Views at a time, so you can animate one into the other (and back).  So your scroll view should have a a pdf view for each of it's pages, and you'll need to clean them out when they move too far out of view or your memory usage will kill you.

Comment: @Mike: Ok yeah, for what I'm doing I need to scroll left and right to go from PDF to PDF, and scroll up and down to view the different pages within the PDF.  Right now I'm using a webView, which is giving me the functionality to scroll up and down.  But I'm having trouble implementing the left and right scrolling

Comment: In your detail view, add a UIScrollView as a subview. Then add each of the web views as subviews of the scroll view, side by side, incrementing the web view frame.origin.x by the width of each view.  When you get an event from the rootViewController (table), you'll need to reposition the scroll view to the right frame  by calling setContentOffset on the scroll view.

Comment: @Mike, right now the way that I would add the webViews is using Interface Builder.  I don't know how to add webViews that are positioned outside of the View.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: In IB, press command-0 (zero) to bring up the Document Window.  Press Shift-Command-L to bring up the library.  Drag a scrollView from library and add it to your detailView.  Then drag a webView and add it to the scroll view. (repeat for as many webViews as you want).  Now, in the Document Window, select the top webView, press the blue/white "i" Inspector button.  In the Inspector window, tap the yellow ruler.  Here you can set the X coordinate of the web views to 0 for the firs webview, then 0+webViewWidth for the 2nd wb, then 0+webViewWidth*2 for 3rd wv, etc.

Comment: @Mike, I figured out how to have the scroll view focus on one PDF at a time, but now I can't get the gesture control to work.  Whenever I try to swipe left or right it just scrolls left or right within whatever PDF I'm looking at.  Thanks alot for all the help by the way, I really appreciate it!

Comment: I'm traveling, not at my Mac. Is there a way to disable horizontal scrolling in the webview - ie can you find a property?